# Add user Control in a page in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I have a windows phone application and I need to add a user control to one of its pages. I want to add it like what in an asp.net page, not as a popup. How can I add this user control to the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your UserControl is in the format of something like:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlExample.NameReporter"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >

<!-- Controls here -->

</UserControl>
```

which it should by default when you create a new UserControl and the code behind is similar to

```
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace UserControlExample
{
    public partial class NameReporter : UserControl
    {
        public NameReporter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // your custom methods here
    }
}
```

you should then be able to add it to the page by using code similar to

```
<Grid xmlns:src="clr-namespace:UserControlExample" 
        Background="White" Margin="0,50,0,0">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <src:NameReporter Grid.Row="0"/>
  <src:NameReporter Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,15,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

Just change the namespace after `clr-namespace:` and the control name after `src:`

You can put the `xmlns:` tag into the `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>` tag instead to use the control throughout the form (rather than just in a grid) and you can change the `src` to whatever you wish to refer to it as.

If the UserControl is created properly, compiling the solution should mean it appears in your Toolbox for use too, so you could then just drag & drop.

See the reference for a fuller example.

> References:
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

For Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone 8.1, I was able to accomplish this by doing the following:

Create your user control. In this example, I created a few Rectangles to mimic the classic mobile menu button.

[image: Your usercontrol]

**Build Solution**. The project will update and you shall see your user control now in the Toolbox.

[image: Toolbox]

Simply drag your user control out of the toolbox and drop it in the XAML page where you wish to use your user control.

[image: UserControl in use]